# Please help to identify the LEGO Set

Tags: set-identification

Please help to identify the LEGO Plastic Bags # (Pack 1-610S7, Pack 2-210S7) I can't even scan the code, it is too small from the camera. These are the packs left over from my son and the boxes were thrown out.   Thank you[image: ![enter image description here]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AWTHf.jpg)

Answer (score 7):

These parts belong to [42060](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=42060-1) set.

[image]

Identified by unique combination of [Technic, Liftarm 1 x 3 Thick with Black '40 1977 - 2017' and 24 Tooth Gear Pattern](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=32523pb11&idColor=1#T=C&C=1)

[image]

and [Technic, Panel Fairing # 2 Small Smooth Short, Side B](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=87086#T=C) in Orange

[image]